# Override instantiateItem - Incompatible return type

Tags: android, wear-os, android-pageradapter

I'm trying to override method `instantiateItem` in my class extending `FragmentGridPgerAdapter`.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.wearable.view.CardFragment;

import android.support.wearable.view.FragmentGridPagerAdapter;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PickerAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter
{
    ...
    @Override
    protected Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int row, int col)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setText("Ahoj");

        viewGroup.addView(textView);
        return textView;
    }
    ...
  }
```

But Android Studio giving me a error on word `Object`:

```
'instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int, int)' in 'com.example.sk1x1.myapplication.PickerAdapter' clashes with 'instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int, int)' in 'android.support.wearable.view.FragmentGridPagerAdapter'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

If I run program, during building I get:

```
Error:(78, 22) error: instantiateItem(ViewGroup,int,int) in PickerAdapter cannot override instantiateItem(ViewGroup,int,int) in GridPagerAdapter
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error:(78, 22) error: instantiateItem(ViewGroup,int,int) in PickerAdapter cannot override instantiateItem(ViewGroup,int,int) in GridPagerAdapter
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

Change

```
@Override
protected Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int row, int col)
```

with

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int row, int col)
```

Comment: if I change method to public, during building i get: `Error:(78, 19) error: instantiateItem(ViewGroup,int,int) in PickerAdapter cannot override instantiateItem(ViewGroup,int,int) in FragmentGridPagerAdapter
return type Object is not compatible with Fragment`

Comment: *return type Object is not compatible with Fragment*,  `public Fragment` instead of `public Object` ? And of course you will have to return a Fragment not a TextView

Comment: If I change return type to `Fragment` and return `new Fragment`, program builds fine, but doesnt work like it should. It doesnt show any `Card`

Answer (score 0):

Like @Blackbelt said, you should have the below function definition and you should return the fragment you want to be returned : a custom one or a card fragment if you want (below an example for the CardFragment).

```
@Override
public Fragment instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int row, int column) {
    return CardFragment.create("title", "text", R.drawable.ic_your_icon);
}
```

`new Fragment()` would return an empty fragment.

On Android Studio, use Ctrl+o to override a function, you will have the correct definition.